# OpenGL: missing GL_SPECULAR light on the texture

Tags: opengl, textures

I'am missing specular lighting on the texture. I have `#include <GL/glext.h>` in the project, so basically I used `glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL_EXT, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR_EXT);` for specular effect. My init code:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
GLfloat AmbientLight[]   = {  0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  1.0 };
GLfloat DiffuseLight[]   = {  0.7,  0.7,  0.7,  1.0 };
GLfloat SpecularLight[]  = {  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0 };
GLfloat Shininess[]      = { 90.0 };
GLfloat Emission[]       = {  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0 };
GLfloat Global_Ambient[] = {  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  1.0 }; 
GLfloat LightPosition[]  = { 7.0, 7.0, 7.0,  1.0 };

glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, Global_Ambient); 
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,LightPosition);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION,  0.05f );
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION,    0.03f );
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.002f);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, Shininess);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, Emission);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); 
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
```

My render code:

```
glClearColor( 0.117f, 0.117f, 0.117f, 1.0f );
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// load texture
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL_EXT, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR_EXT);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2);      
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
// render geometry here
glFlush();
```

What is missing here?

Comment: as I said I tried `glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL_EXT, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR_EXT);` and also tried multipass with `glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` and this did not work either.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing"? Do you have a screenshot? Specular depends a lot on the geometry you're rendering. If it's very sparse you may not see the effect. Do you still have this problem if you render a sphere with a ton of faces? Finally, have you tried much higher specular exponents (AKA shininess)?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: [link](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/095/5/4/spec_by_nightkn8-d7d5vpd.png). Fig.1 shows color stage with specular ON, Fig.2 shows my problem, the specular light is ON but there is no shiny effect on the textured surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I got it... The problem was that my program was using old dll `opengl32.dll` that was located in the same folder. After removing the old dll the rendering context automatically switched to the local dll's: `atioglxx.dll` for AMD and `nvoglv32.dll` for NVidia. So basically now the `glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_COLOR_CONTROL_EXT, GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR_EXT);` is working as it should. Thank you for your interest.